# Display in msgbox unique values

Tags: excel, vba, unique

I hope you don't mind me asking whether there is an easier way to do what I want to achieve. Whilst my code 'works', it feels quite inefficient and I'd like to understand a quicker way of doing it:

I have a list of account client numbers in column A of my worksheet; and in column Q I have used the UNIQUE formula to determine my unique values. There can't be any more than 5 unique client numbers (but it could be as low as 1) and so I've written the following:

```
Option Explicit
Sub list()

Dim value1 As Long, value2 As Long, value3 As Long, value4 As Long, value5 As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

 value1 = ws.Cells(5, 17).Value
 value2 = ws.Cells(6, 17).Value
 value3 = ws.Cells(7, 17).Value
 value4 = ws.Cells(8, 17).Value
 value5 = ws.Cells(9, 17).Value
 
MsgBox "Clients numbers used: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & value1 & vbCrLf & value2 & vbCrLf & value3 & vbCrLf & value4 & vbCrLf & value5, vbInformation
        

End Sub
```

I presume it would be possible to build an array of the unique values in VBA then only 'print' the ones that actually appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the message directly from the range of cells.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub list()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, s As String, i As Long
    Dim cel As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    For Each cel In ws.Range("Q5:Q9")
        If Len(cel.value2) > 0 Then
            s = s & vbCrLf & cel.value2
        End If
    Next
     
    MsgBox "Clients numbers used: " & s, vbInformation
            
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have a variable number of arguments, `ParamArray` is a way of approaching it.  You just have to process a bit differently if the reference is a Range or an array.

And you can determine uniqueness in various ways entirely within VBA. I demonstrate the use of ArrayList (because it can also sort easily if you want that). If sorting is not an issue, you could use a Dictionary or a Collection.

Note that ArrayList cannot sort a mixture of numbers and strings, so you might want to use a different method if that might be an issue.

For example:

```
Option Explicit
Function list5(ParamArray X() As Variant) As String
    Dim AL As Object
    Dim V As Variant, W As Variant, Y As Variant
    
Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each V In X
    Select Case TypeName(V)
        Case "Range"
            For Each Y In V
                If Not AL.contains(Y.Value2) Then AL.Add (Y.Value2)
            Next Y
        Case "Variant()"
            For Each Y In V
                If Not AL.contains(Y) Then AL.Add (Y)
            Next Y
        Case Else
            If Not AL.contains(V) Then AL.Add (V)
    End Select
Next V

'cannot sort mixture of numbers and strings
On Error Resume Next
    AL.Sort
On Error GoTo 0

V = AL.toarray

MsgBox Join(V, vbLf)

End Function
```

The argument to the function can be a range, a string or number, or an array constant, or even a combination of these.